# How can I update the subviews in a UIScrollView after I dismissModalView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing

I'm using parse as a backend so all of my data is in parse. I programmatically created a UIScrollView and am adding it to my tableView Cells contentView. When the scrollView is added, I iterate through a parse query array and create a labels for all of the items in the array then set the labels text to the NSStrings in the array. I then add the label to the subview of the scrollView. I add items to this this subview with an IBAction so every time I hit a button it adds text to the parse array and then the text is set to the label allowing it to display in the scrollView.

I want the users to be able to edit the data so I have a button labeled edit. When this button is pressed, a modal view is presented and it's a tableView of all the items that I want to be edited. When I delete the items in the tableview and dismiss the view, the scrollview doesn't update. The only time the scrollview updates with the proper data from parse is if I close the app out and reopen.

In short, I have 2 screens, how can I update data in the scrollView of the original screen when the modal view is dismissed. I'm not sure why I have to close the app down in order to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to call a method `refresh` when the modal view is dismissed (or create such a method if it doesn't exist -- it should be just a chunk of code you already had somewhere else, possibly in the `viewDidLoad`).

The reason you get correct data when you close and reopen the app: it refreshes the data when it opens.

Another thing: since you're using Parse, it's async, which means the data isn't available immediately when the modal view is dismissed (ie it needs to be sent to the Parse server and get stored in the Parse database). Add a delay before calling `refresh` method. Or better, wait until data is fully sync before you actually dismiss the modal view (display a 'Saving...' HUD, etc)

Comment: The weird thing is that I alloc init my scrollview in the cellForRowAtIndex Path only if it's empty. Using (!self.scrollView). All of my subviews are added to the scrollView but now the subviews keep overlapping each other. Until I close the app out then everything displays normal. What runs at the beginning of the app that could reset the view that I can maybe re run on view will disappear?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I ended up setting all of my labels in the block and using delegates.